# Why doesn't my defined 'walk' method of the 'Dog' class get inherited by the 'Bulldog' or 'Russell Terrier' child classes?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, methods

In my last line of code, when i call the 'walk()' method , nothing happens. But when I run it in the console, i get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2, in
>    AttributeError: 'Bulldog' object has no attribute 'walk'

```
class Pets:

    def __init__(self,dogs):
        self.dogs=dogs


class Dog:

    # Class attribute
    species = 'mammal'

    # Initializer / Instance attributes
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.is_hungry = True

# instance method
    def eat(self):
        self.is_hungry = False

#Walk instance method
    def walk(self):
        return "{} is walking!" .format(self.name)

# Child class (inherits from Dog class)
class RussellTerrier(Dog):
    def run(self, speed):
        return "{} runs {}".format(self.name, speed)

# Child class (inherits from Dog class)
class Bulldog(Dog):
    def run(self, speed):
        return "{} runs {}".format(self.name, speed)

# create isntances of dogs
my_dogs = [
    Bulldog("Tom", 6),
    RussellTerrier("Fletcher", 7),
    Dog("Larry", 9)
]

my_Pets=Pets(my_dogs)

#walking

for doggy in my_Pets.dogs:
    doggy.walk()
```

Comment: Aside: It'd make our lives easier if this were formatted in a way that could be copied-and-pasted into a REPL.

Comment: Also, is it intentional that you're using old-style classes (not inheriting from `object`)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I had no trouble doing the copy-paste.

Comment: What Python version are you using?  When I insert the missing `print` commands, I get a smooth execution that walks all three dogs.

Comment: @Prune, copy/paste into a file works fine her, but into a REPL? The whitespace is wrong for it.

Comment: Works fine for me too @ https://ideone.com/LoP2M3 (only changes there being whitespace edited).

Comment: It looks like you have an extra space in the "walk" function before the .format

Comment: @Prune, ...re: copyability-into-a-repl (without whitespace changes), see https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/149a06a9b3dac18092fcb3514a57e64b

Comment: why do I need the print function? i have specified   return "{} is walking!".format(self.name) . am new to Python so apologies for dumb question if it is

Comment: @user10433947, ...except in special cases like the REPL (which is a development tool more than a real runtime environment), returning something doesn't automatically print it. If it did, you could never have a function calculate anything that wasn't supposed to be immediately printed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `walk` method is returning a `string`. If you are expecting it to print the string, then you need to do that explicitly. Your last two lines should be:

```
for doggy in my_Pets.dogs:
    print(doggy.walk())
```

Your issue with the `AttributeError` is most likely the way you are copy-pasting it into the console.

Comment: Then can you also explain why OP is getting `'Bulldog' object has no attribute 'walk'`?

Comment: The OP reported an AttributeError. This doesn't address that.